# I need help writing a program that prints out two shapes next to each other using nested loops

Tags: python, for-loop, shapes

I need two print two triangle shapes next to each other using for loops in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using a recursive approach as well. You can invert the printing of levels like the solution below.

```
def line_print(samples, level=0):
    if samples == 0:
        return
    line_print(samples-1, level+1)
    print(f"{'*'*samples}{' '* level*2} {'*'*samples}")

# Call the function with needed levels
line_print(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

For each row you need to print

- stars an amount of times that is the row index starting at 1
- spaces to complete to the total size
- then the 2 previous the other way
- with a space in the middle, given by `print` between the 2 parts

```
def print_valley(size):
    for row in range(1, 1 + size):
        print("*" * row + " " * (size - row),
              " " * (size - row) + "*" * row)
```

---

A maybe more easy to understand version

```
def print_valley(size):
    for row in range(1, 1 + size):
        star = "*" * row
        space = " " * (size - row)
        print(star + space, space + star)
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty obvious homework question to me. Are we really doing what's best for Mohammad by doing his homework for him? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions